# Использование 64-bit кода и 32-bit данных

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Какие преимущества дает использование 64-bit кода и 32-bit данных?

Comment: Что подразумевается под 32-х битными данными?

Comment: @eanmos, Гарвардская архитектура, ширина канала инструкций отличается от ширина канала данных :) Мне только это в голову приходит, но пусть ТС объясняет.

Comment: Реже срежутся данные

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, объясните немного подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Единственное, что мне приходит в голову (предполагаю архитектуру Intel 64), это оптимизация по размеру инструкции. В long mode инструкции, оперирующие над quad words (64 бита) обычно длинее чем те, которые работают с double words (32 бита). Поэтому там, где можно использовать последние, лучше использовать их. Классический пример: для обнуления 64-битного регистра стоит использовать не `xor R64, R64`, а `xor R32, R32`, потому что такая операция обнулит не только 32-битную часть `EAX`, например, но и 64-битную часть этого регистра. Результат одинаковый, размер инструкций разный.

Comment: Думаю достаточно будет читать     https://digitark.ee/ru/32bit-64bit/

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в статье как минимум одна грубая ошибка: "32-битная система" *способна* работать с  памятью большей 4GB, если процессор поддерживает PAE.

Comment: @isnullxbh, да не за что :) Будем ждать, может, у кого-то есть и другие идеи.

Comment: @eanmos, честно говоря не охота уделять время для внимательного чтения, но проводя взгляд, я не нашел такого выражения, хотя  ошибка в одном выражении не  делает статью бесполезной.

Comment: Еще одна причина использовать 32-х битные данные: 64-х битные данные занимают вдвое больше места в кэше, чем 32-х битные, что может несколько снизить производительность.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Кодов команд обычно мало, 256 (1 байт=8 бит) ну или 65536 (два байта=16 бит). Трудно представить систему, в которой нужно 4 млрд команд (32 бита) и тем более 64 бита. А вот разрядность данных все стараются увеличить (тоже, правда, в разумных пределах). Разве сейчас есть системы с 64-bit кода и 32-bit данных?

Comment: @isnullxbh,   имелось ввиду обработка большего количества данных. Это как  использовать  боьшой экскаватор с 4 кубовым обьемом ковша , чтобы обработать 2 куба грунта каждым махом(может пример и неудачный, но надеюсь меня поймут)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вроде бы понял) Спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score 2):

*<sup>Я предполагаю, что речь идет об архитектуре Intel 64 (x86_64) и под 32-битными данными подразумеваются double words и 32-битные регистры.</sup>*

Использование 32-битных данных вместо 64-битных имеет смысл по нескольким причинам:

1. Quad words (64 бита) занимают вдвое больше памяти, чем double words (32 бита) в кэше процессора. Использование последних позволяет использовать кэш более экономно, что может положительно сказаться на производительности.
2. Инструкции, оперирующие над quad words и 64-битными регистрами обычно длинее чем те, что работают с double words и 32-битными регистрами. Поэтому там, где можно использовать последние, лучше использовать их<sup>1</sup>.

   Классический пример: для обнуления 64-битного регистра стоит использовать не

   ```
   xor R64, R64
   ```

   а 32-битную версию этого регистра:

   ```
   xor R32, R32
   ```

   потому что такая операция обнулит не только 32-битную часть `EAX`, например, но и его 64-битную часть. Результат одинаковый, размер инструкций разный. Что опять же положительно скажется на производительности: а) инструкция будет занимать меньше места в кэше; б) уменьшится размер бинарного файла.
3. Если нам нужно поддерживать и 32-, и 64-битную версию программы, имеет смысл использовать 32-битные данные, чтобы уменьшить различие между версиями и сделать их сопровождение более простым.

---

<sup>1. Это не всегда возможно. Например, в 64-bit mode мы не можем положить на стек (`push`) 32-х битное значение.</sup>